# Did Shotwell move my images on first launch after upgrade to ubuntu 20.4.1? If so, how do I reverse this?

Tags: 20.04, shotwell

Ubuntu, Shotwell Users and Devs,

Quick Summary:

Using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Release, Desktop, with default Gnome (not a special release, generic kernel, iso from ubuntu download page). Then added shotwell with apt get install shotwell (installed Shotwell 0.30.10). On invoking shotwell from the command line (% shotwell) the gui version launched without error or messages, but apparently began moving images without a prompt, notification, or asking with a dialog box.

How do I return the images to their original location?  Does shotwell keep a log of what files are moved and from where?

Longer Version, originally posted here:

Context:

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20, at first launch of $ shotwell from the command line (no options, no configs) which invokes program, which apparently began to either move or copy images.

This is from the same home directory used for ubuntu 16 and 18

Result:

Unable to find images in former locations, but they appear to now be in ~/Pictures.  How did that happen?

Question:

How do I reverse this?  The images are stored in directories which archive specific devices.  Moving them destroys the archives and backups.

Why this change in shotwell's behavior from ubuntu 16 and 18?

Any help would be appreciated.  I also thank the devs for your work on a very good program.

Comment: Ubuntu 20? 16? 18?  No such releases, do you mean Ubuntu Core 16? Ubuntu Core 18? & Ubuntu Core 20?  Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* format for server & desktop, with *yy* being used by specialist *snap* based releases.   *yy* releases don't include a GUI, so use of `shotwell` doesn't make sense, let alone this being a user support site (not a site frequented by *devs*)

Comment: More precision then: $ lsb_release -a ... Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Release: 20.04 Codename: focal.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases lists multiple releases of 14, 16, 18 and 20.
So read 16.04.7, 18.04.5 and 20.04.1 LTE releases, Desktop (not Server) with whatever stock Gnome Desktop is included

$ shotwell -V: Shotwell 0.30.10  

So does Shotwell 0.30.10 on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1 LTS move files when it runs
for the first time? It did not on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.5 LTS or 16.04.7 LTS. Installed from apt get install ((0.30.10-0ubuntu0.1), not snap.

Comment: Correct the details on your question  (you want the most number of people reading it, in order to get the most & fastest responses).  Ubuntu uses *yy* for different releases to the *yy.mm* format; so references to release should be clear. That wiki page only refers to server & desktop releases, making no mention of *specialist* or *yy* format releases.

Comment: @guiverc Edited question, but not sure I follow. Tags here (created at the same time as original question) only allow 20.04 and will not accept 20.04.1 (needs 300+ to create). Am I misreading the wiki page? The wiki page appears to reference all the yy releases, and specialist release (like flavors?) would not be called Ubuntu, correct (i.e., Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu)? What are the specialist releases of Ubuntu? Does Ubuntu.com list them somewhere?

Comment: 20.04.1 should be tagged as 20.04 anyway; I'd have removed my prior comments except your question still mixes up 20.04, and what I read as Ubuntu Core 20 (you miss out the Core though), and  older Core versions 16 & 18; ie. it's still unclear though has improved.  If you look at the wiki page you linked, I'm in it's history as editing it, so I am somewhat aware of what it represents; but I see no reference to any *yy* release; all releases are *yy.mm* in format as the document only refers to desktop & server releases, not appliance/device or specialist releases with 10 year support

Comment: @guiverc OK; that's interesting, so I'll keep checking back for an actual answer or comment about shotwell. But let's continue: as near as I can tell, the wiki pages lists all of the Ubuntu yy releases. They are designated Ubuntu yy.mm, correct? There is no mention of Core, special, or flavor releases. If 20.04.1 is tagged here as 20.04, and the question has no reference to Core, why would you read 20.04 as Core? Does the tag 20.04 here on askubuntu mean Core, or Ubuntu 20.04.x?

Comment: Ubuntu *yy* releases don't use deb packages, being full *snap* based releases intended for IoT appliances/devices. They are all LTS releases with 10 years of support (longer than the 5 years offered for *yy.mm* releases, though *yy.mm* can be extended via use of ESM). Your use of 16, 18 & 20 imply Ubuntu Core releases due to the format used where GUI programs particularly are different to due confinement model mandated by running as *snaps*.

Comment: @guiverc Got it; makes sense now. Core looks like it uses an image type of repository, with a snap installer, but I'm not familiar. This question refers to plain old vanilla Desktop with stock XWindows Gnome, 16.04.7, 18.04.5, and 20.04.1. Thanks.

Comment: If it refers to 16.04.7, it doesn't say so (*only comments do and don't expect users to read comments*), instead your question still refers to 16 as used by *snap* based releases, like it states *snap* based 18 and not 18.04.5, and *snap* based 20 instead of mentioning only 20.04..  Most users use *yy.mm* releases and thus ignore the *yy* mentioned questions due to differences & complexities; your question as written mixes both.